# Obtain the same ID from the contact picker and cursor

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-cursor

I'm using a contact picker as such:

```
startActivityForResult(
    new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        Phone.CONTENT_URI
    ), CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT //1001
);
```

This type of contact picker picks out a specific phone number that a contact has.

I then get an ID for this contact with:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT || resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    String id = data.getData.getLastPathSegment();
}
```

However, when I use a PhoneLookup query, such as:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
    Uri.withAppendedPath(
        PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
        Uri.encode(...) //phone number of contact is filled in
    ),
    new String[] {
        PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
        Phone._ID
    }, null, null, null
);

if (!cur.moveToFirst())
    return;

String id = cur.getString(
    cur.getColumnIndex(Phone._ID)
);
```

The ID I get from the PhoneLookup is **different** from the onActivityResult. For example, the contact picker returns 1408 while the cursor returns 444.

How can I get:

`data.getData().getLastPathSegment()` equal to `cur.getColumnIndex(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a PhoneLookup in this case. You need to query Phone.CONTENT_URI to obtain the ID that matches up with the contact picker. The following code below does exactly this.

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
    Phone.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] {
        Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        Phone._ID
    },
    Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER + "=?",
    new String[] {
        ... //phone number placed here
    }, null);
    if (!cur.moveToFirst())
        return;

String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Phone._ID)));
```